# Adaptive TextBox Content

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am getting the content of my text box  from a web rest Api (i.e by binding it to a observable collection). Now for a particular item some content is more for some it is less and I have another grid below it which have three icons in it. Now I want the textbox to be adaptive for large content in text box the icons should always be below the content.

[image: For large content]
[image: For small content]

Now for small content  the icons should automatically come below the text. How should I achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to dock the buttons on the bottom of the view then you can change the row heights to be something like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

In this layout the buttons will take only the height they need while the textblock will take the rest of the available space. Just make sure the textblock is on row 0 and the buttons are on row 1. Or adjust if you have a header (header on row 0, textblock on row 1 and buttons on row 2).